# How to fix: odd and even pages have different margin

Tags: formatting, margins

I want that all the pages (odd und even) of my thesis document have the same geometry but the problem is that [image: picture]the odd and the even pages have different margin

Here is my configuration:

```
-------
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
    left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2cm,
}
```

Can someone help me please how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option `asymmetric`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  %showframe,
  left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  asymmetric% <- added
}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this Problen can be fixed with 
\documentclass[
oneside,
] too

Answer (score 0):

This is what I obtain with your setting.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2cm,
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image: example_image1]
[image: example_image2]

I suggest you to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't post your full thesis.